# 2007 Ford E350 electrical problem

Tags: electrical, electronics, power-windows, dashboard, instrument-cluster

My 12 passenger ford E350 2007 occasionally (random times while driving for random duration 5 -40 minutes) loses power to the:

- dashboard
- stero
- and windows.

What can be wrong with my car? How do I diagnose what is wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: When?  Random times, just after starting, going over a bump in a road, at night, when hot, when cold, in the rain?

Comment: @HandyHowie random times while driving for random duration 5 -40 minutes

Comment: Does turning the ignition off and on fix it?  Obviously not while driving!

Comment: @HandyHowie turning the ignition off and then on does not fix the problem. Hard turning may fix the problem (I am not sure that it really works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a loose fuse or fuses or loose connectors somewhere or even broken wires.

Only method is to start checking all the relevant fuses and connectors systematically to find out which is the culprit.

Often, all you need to do is wiggle the wires into the fuse box and if the stereo goes off then you have a clue. this applies to connectors as well.

Lots of patience and being thorough is required.